# Yii queryBuilder; If dbexpression is not being quoted well

Tags: yii2

I have this query :

```
 $query->select('if(bud.posa=2,1,0) AS proprietaire,if(bud.du=1 and bud.gog=1,1,0) as pa')->from('bud');
```

if I execute it is giving synthax error; I try to echo the sql that is being generated I found that it is not being generated(quoting problem) well, here is what is generated:

```
select if(bud.posa=2, `1`, `0)` AS `proprietaire`, if(bud.du=1 and bud.gog=1, `1`, `0)` AS `pa` FROM `bud`
```

`0)` is what is causing the error ,I don't see how to solve it,Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the query like this:

```
$query->select([
    'proprietaire' => 'if(bud.posa=2,1,0)',
    'pa'           => 'if(bud.posa=2,1,0)',
]);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#select()-detail

Answer (score 0):

Try so:

`use yii\db\Expression;
.......
.......
$expresion = new Expresion('if(bud.posa=2,1,0) AS proprietaire,if(bud.du=1 and bud.gog=1,1,0) as pa');
$query->select($expresion)->from('bud');`